# Changing mouse pointer not maintained in c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms application that simply has one button.  I created this application to demonstrate what is happening on a much larger application.

The button changes a boolean from true to false, and sets the mouse pointer.

```
private bool ChangeMouse = true;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CURSOR-TOP: " + System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.ToString());

    if (ChangeMouse)
    {
        ChangeMouse = false;
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
    }
    else
    {
        ChangeMouse = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("CURSOR-BOTTOM: " + System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

This is the result I get when i click the button 4 times:

```
CURSOR-TOP: [Cursor: Default]
CURSOR-BOTTOM: [Cursor: Cross]

CURSOR-TOP: [Cursor: Default]
CURSOR-BOTTOM: [Cursor: Default]

CURSOR-TOP: [Cursor: Default]
CURSOR-BOTTOM: [Cursor: Cross]

CURSOR-TOP: [Cursor: Default]
CURSOR-BOTTOM: [Cursor: Default]
```

As can be seen, the value for CURSOR-TOP is always the Default Cursor.  Why is the change to the current cursor not maintained???

Comment: I believe I already figured this out.  I have to use this.Cursor instead of System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.

Comment: Not exactly sure why System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current wouldn't work.  Anyone ?

Comment: Controls determine the cursor shape with their [Cursor property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.cursor?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).  Cursor.Current is only useful if the program is busy, not dispatching messages.  Ideally that never happens.

Answer (score 0):

this.Cursor must be used instead of System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.

As to why?  I really don't know.

Comment: Maybe the static member is updated by some other window. Is the result different if you make sure that you _don't_ move the cursor away from the button between the clicks?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but...

I use this code all the time (I have it in maybe 10 desktop utility apps):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyAppsNamespace
{
    public class WorkingCursor : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Cursor _oldCursor;

        public WorkingCursor()
        {
            _oldCursor = Cursor.Current;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Cursor.Current = _oldCursor;
        }
    }
}
```

You consume it this way:

```
using (new WorkingCursor()) {
    DoSomethingThatTakesAWhile();
}
```

It always just works like a charm.  Not sure why you are having this issue